# How to hide an option from a radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button, acrobat

I want to create a form with Adobe Acrobat.
I have a CheckBox (named CheckBox) and radio buttons (group name: Group1; options name Opt1 Opt2 Opt3).

With this code in the actions of the CheckBox (run a JavaScript script):

```
var nDisplay = event.target.isBoxChecked (0)? display.visible: display.hidden;
this.getField ("Group1"). display = nDisplay;
```

I manage to hide the group (= all options). But I would like to hide only one option (Opt3 for example).
How do I modify my code to achieve this result?
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your example you add the name of the group to the getfield function:`this.getField ("Group1")`. This means you are hiding the full group. In order to hide a single option you should instead add the name of that specific option to the getfield function `this.getField ("Opt3")`

So your code should look like this:

```
var nDisplay = event.target.isBoxChecked (0)? display.visible: display.hidden;
this.getField ("Opt3"). display = nDisplay;
```

Comment: I tried this idea before: replace "Group1" with "Opt3". But it doesn't matter when I do an action on my CheckBox.
I also tried using "Group2.Opt3", thinking that I needed to define the group of the option to select.

Comment: Have you tried changing `display.hidden` to `display.none`?

Comment: I got the [original code here](https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Hiding-and-Showing-Form-Fields.cfm?sd=40)
But I just tested by replacing "display.hidden" by "display.none": no more checkbox action

Comment: @IFE You mean no more action when you have `this.getField ("Opt3")` or `this.getField ("Group1")`?

Comment: I want that when I check the CheckBox, the Opt3 option is visible or hidden.
To summarize my tests and your proposals (compared to my original code):
- replace "Group2" by "Opt3": nothing works anymore
- replace "display.hidden" by "display.none" (with this.getField ("Group2") or this.getField ("Opt3")): nothing works anymore

I think it's a matter of finding the right nomenclature to name the Opt3 offer, but I don't know enough about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By dint of research and testing, I finally found the solution.
The problem was with the name of the option. I had this intuition.

In Adobe Acrobat (form), when you create radio buttons, they are part of a group (example "Group1") and each new button will be named "Opt1" "Opt2" ...
To draw a parallel with other languages, the group is actually "a list". So the name of the option "Opt1" is not "Opt1" but the 1st element of "the list" (= "Group1"): Group1.0
And with that, it's won.

I take my original code which hides all group ("Group1"):

```
var nDisplay = event.target.isBoxChecked (0)? display.visible: display.hidden;
this.getField ("Group1"). display = nDisplay;
```

If I want to do an action on the 1st element of the list (= "Opt1"), the code would become:

```
var nDisplay = event.target.isBoxChecked (0)? display.visible: display.hidden;
this.getField ("Group1.0"). display = nDisplay;
```

(1st element = 0; 2nd element = 1 ...)

Thanks to Stephen for taking the time to help me :) And I hope it helps other people.